# Huge distortion with the 16mm lens

Tags: optics, sony, wide-angle, sony-nex

Today I've tried my new lens, but the image was very distorted in the right side.
Here's the image:

[image]

Is this normal? (The building on the right is very skewed)

Bigger image: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bSve.jpg)

Comment: Out of interest, which lens are you using here?

Comment: Sony's SEL16F28

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Distortion caused by a lens's optics would give you barrel distortion (objects appear to bulge outward) or pincushion distortion (squishing inward). The skewed lines you are observing are straight; this is [perspective distortion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)), and is not a problem caused by the lens nor fixable with better optics (you can fix it with a tilt-shift lens, but that's a special type of lens).

You can read more about exactly what perspective distortion is and how to deal with it [here](http://digital-photography-school.com/why-are-my-buildings-falling-over-a-short-guide-to-perspective-distortion-and-correction-in-photography).

Answer (score 6):

You're getting what is called Perspective distortion which is most noticable in wide angle lenses. Check out this link for more info:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)

Basically close up objects in the center of the frame will look enlarged while objects on the sides will be stretched away from the center of the photo.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph. Only if the object on the sides are further from the camera. If you are using a rectilinear wide angle lens to photograph a flat wall at a close distance, one inch squares at the edges of the frame will appear *larger* than a one inch square at the center.